# rollup 'rollup-plugin-postcss' dont inject css into head

Tags: css, web-component, rollup

I want to create an HTML web component and i need to import CSS file but I want to inject it into my shadow dom. I have some code like below:

```
import introHTML from './Intro.html';
import introCss from './Intro.css';
class IntroWebComponent extends HTMLElement{

constructor(){
    super();
    this.defineClassProp();
}
defineClassProp(){
    this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    this._html = introHTML
    this._element = document.createElement('template');
    this._element.innerHTML = this._html;
    this._element.append(`<style>${introCss}</style>`)
    this._shadowRoot.appendChild(this._element.content.cloneNode(true));
}

}
window.customElements.define('index-intro', IntroWebComponent);
```

but 'rollup-plugin-postcss' keep injecting css to my main html head and i dont know how to stop it

Answer (score 2):

just config your rollup to stop inject style in your js module:
the default config is:

```
postcss({
    inject: { insertAt: 'top' }
})
```

you must change it to:

```
postcss({
  inject:false
})
```